# Copy an inherited class to another in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

anyone knows how to get all properties from an inherited class and put the current properties in just one Object with ES6?

```
export class MainClass  {

   constructor(classInstance) {} 

   myMethodMain {
     //doSomhethig
   }  
}
```

<kbd>file 2</kbd>

```
class Another extends MainClass {

  constructor(config) {
      this.name = 'testing';
  }

  myMethodAnother {
  //doSomhethig
  }
}
```

<kbd>file 3</kbd>

```
class RandomClass {
    constructor() {
      this.name = 'test';
    }
    myMethodRamdonChild { 
    //doSomhethig
    }
}
```

<kbd>file 3</kbd>

```
class RandomChild extends RandomClass {
    myMethodRamdonChild {
    //doSomhethig
   }
}

export const myMainClass = new Another(new RandomChild());
```

I need in the constructor of my MainClass copy all properties from RandomChild and the super class RandomClass and maintain the current properties from my current class too.
In the final i need an Object with all properties like that.

```
newObject{
  myMethodMain {
  //doSomhethig
  }
  myMethodAnother {
  //doSomhethig
  }
  myMethodRamdonChild { 
    //doSomhethig
  }
  myMethodRamdonChild {
    //doSomhethig
  }
}
```

I have tried to use(`_.merge, _.copy, angular.copy, angular.merge, $.merge, Object.assign, Object.merge`) and other methods.

Important: I can't change my current structure

Comment: Please accept the correct answer instead of changing the title into `solved`. Self accepting is allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved my problem with this.

```
export const bind = (target) => (obj) => isFunction(target) ? target.bind(obj) : target;

export const pack = (keys) => (obj) => keys.reduce((res, key) => Object.assign(res, {[key]: bind(obj[key])(obj)}), {});

export const getAllProperties = (o) => {
    let results = [];

    function properties(obj) {
        let props, i;
        if (obj == null) {
            return results;
        }
        if (typeof obj !== 'object' && typeof obj !== 'function') {
            return properties(obj.constructor.prototype);
        }
        props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
        i = props.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (!~results.indexOf(props[i])) {
                results.push(props[i]);
            }
        }
        return properties(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
    }

    return properties(o);
};

Object.assign(self, pack(getAllProperties(jmi))(jmi));
```

`self` has all properties from my classes :)

Comment: Instead of `obj.constructor.prototype`, you really want `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object(obj))`